# Formatting a NSTextField for credit card input like (xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx) [macOS Swift]

Tags: swift, string, macos, cocoa, string-formatting

I want to format a NSTextField for credit card input like (xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx)
I tried the below code

```
   func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification){
   let number = card.stringValue.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

    if(number.count % 4 == 0){
        card.stringValue = card.stringValue+" "
    }
  }
```

This works fine but when I give a backspace I seem to have a problem.

Is there a better way to format my string

Answer (score -2):

I'm using `UITextField` but I believe that it's very similar to `NSTextField`

```
// remember to do this
textField.delegate = self

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let number = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    if ((number?.count ?? 0) % 4 == 0 && string != "") {
        textField.text! += " "
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Bro,I've don't the same thing for macOS but this method fails when you press delete key